# Why does my code not execute after await statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, promise, async-await

I have a problem with an javascript react app that uses google firebase for authentication.....the code after "await" is not executed and chrome does some strange reload (it seems).

I have tried to rebuild what I have seems in this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_wZCW6wXIo

https://github.com/mehulmpt/firebase-react-hooks

Here is my Login.js

```
...
....
      <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
        <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
      </Form.Group>
      <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={login}>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );

async function login() {
    try {
      console.log("l1");
      await firebase.login(email, password);
      console.log("l2");
      debugger;
      props.history.replace("/impressum");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("l3");
      alert(error.message);
    }
  }
```

And here the firebase.js helper class:

```
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
    this.auth = app.auth();
    this.db = app.firestore();
  }

  login(email, password) {
    return this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }
...
...
```

When I run the app with "npm start" (its a react app), open the Chrome Developer Window for the console and the debugger and then hit the "submit"-Button of my Login-Form I see the "l1" log output in the console for about half a second. Then the developer-window seems to reaload, the console seems to be reset, the "l1" disappears and "l2", "l3" does not appear at all. And the debugger does not stop at the breakpoints and the redirect to "/impressum" is not executed as well.

I am desperate now. I tried hundreds of variations my async, await, then, catch....I even don't know if my code is wrong or if my chrome has a problem (but its the same in firefox).

I hope you have a hint.

Comment: Instead of asking a new question please edit your existing, identical question with the new information you provide here. Alternatively you can delete your old question and vote to reopen this one.

Answer (score 3):

Browser-side JavaScript programs run in the context of a web page.

Submit buttons submit forms.

When a form is submitted, the browser navigates to a new web page.

Since the page the JS program was running in has been navigated away from, that JS program exits. It does this before reaching `console.log("l2");`

You probably want to [prevent the default behaviour of the submit button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Comment: Hi Quentin, I dont know if you can read this, because my post was closed, but I love you. Hours of desperation and than it just was "event.preventDefault()". Crazy. Tahnk you very much